# Are MySQL SELECT queries case-insensitive?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I have a form with method post, users will filter results by brand date etc.
If the brand name in the MySQL is stored with non lowercase example ( samsung ) and the search input field is filled with uppercase example ( SAMSUNG ) will it still give me the correct results or will cause errors ?

```
$branded=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['brand']); // USER TYPED SAMSUNG
}
$query= "SELECT * FROM `brands` WHERE `brand` = '$branded' LIMIT 1"; // stored as samsung
```

Comment: I don't see how it would give an error. It would just return no match. But it would depend on the collation that you use. Some are case sensitive and some are not. If you are using case-sensitive, you could always lower-case the user text in php before running query.

Comment: why don't you just test it out and see what happens?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Calling the escaping functions manually is not just a lot more work, it's also an opportunity to make a serious mistake.

Comment: `describe \`brands\`` will answer your question. if the `COLLATE` instruction of the result finishes by `_ci`, then it is case insensitive.

Comment: It says latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locale is "latin1_swedish_ci".

Because it ends in "ci", it must be **c**ase-**i**nsensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Most MySQL collations are case-insensitive, unless you are doing a binary comparison.  In your query case shouldn't change anything. However the following query would mark "samsung" and "SAMSUNG" as different:

```
$branded=mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['brand']); // USER TYPED SAMSUNG
}
$query= "SELECT * FROM `brands` WHERE BINARY `brand` = '$branded' LIMIT 1"; // stored as samsung
```

You would have to check your collation to know for sure whether it is case-sensitive but the easiest way would just be to test it.

Use this link as a reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html